# NextJs, Redux, Redux Saga generic reducers example

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

Hi i heard from my friend that exist function which generate automatically reducer so you don't need write switch and case just define initial state and action types.

I am creating new project with Next.js, Redux, Redux Saga and i would like use this function.

I would ask you what you think about it? What's are advantages and disadvantages in this case. If you are using it can you share with me example code please?

Thank you for your answers :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer/

Comment: @UtsavPatel that seems good thanks :)